# Auto-Resizing TableViewCell based on content not working

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm trying to have UITableViewCells automatically being resized based on the content of the cell; however, the row height doesn't change at all, so the content is clipped.

I have a UITableViewController with one prototype cell. In that there is a UI view pinned with 0 top, bottom, leading and trailing constraints. To that view, I added an ImageView with fixed width and height, centered in the view and with top constraints. Additionally, there is a centered label with top and bottom constraints.
So constraints should be set up fine.

Furthermore, I added

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 300
```

to the `viewDidLoad()` of the `TableViewController`.

Instead of getting the expected result

[image]

the screen looks like this:

[image]

Here are the Constraints:

[image: Here is the Constraints]

Any ideas what's happening here?

EDIT:
Just for testing purposes, I now created a new prototype cell and only added a label to it, pinning it with leading, trailing, top and bottom constraints and setting its `lines`property to `0` in order to enable AutoResize. However, again nothing is happening, the label doesn't even wrap the text inside it.

See here for storyboard and constraints and actual result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIaR1.jpg

My TableViewController code:

```swift
import UIKit

class FirstTableViewController: UITableViewController{


    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension

        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 300.0

    }


    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return 1
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cellA = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "article", for: indexPath) as! ArticleTableViewCell
            cellA.articleText.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus "
            return cellA

    }
}
```

Comment: Why is there an extra view inside content view? Any specific reason?

Comment: Yeah, for later to enable shadows and rounded corners

Comment: isn't `tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension` giving any synax error?

Comment: @RevanthKausikan No, that's the old UITableViewAutomaticDimension since swift 4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just deleted that TableViewController and started from scratch. Now everything is working fine...

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are setting leading and trailing constraint on label to its superView, only Horizontal Center constraint is not enough.

[Alternatively, you can choose also set fixed width without height on label. **Do not set the height of Label** : see updated answer below]

Also you would want to set numberOfLines on label to 0, if you want it to grow based on content.

Thats how Label height will be calculated.

I tried with a little demo and it works just fine for me.

[image]

[image]

**Update**:

Do not set height on the label, as it will fix its height and will not grow based on content.

As suggested by Revanth, width is enough, thats your choice to either set "width" or "leading and trailing" constraint on label.

But make sure its height is flexible and numberOfLines = 0 for it to grow.

Comment: Your first line is not true. If necessary width and centre constraint is given, it is enough. The only possibility is that you might get warning for your content getting clipped.

Comment: @RevanthKausikan You are correct, I've just given best option. Anyway is fine as far as height can be inferred from the label.  Updated the answer

Comment: Even with your suggestions (adding leading and trailing constraints; removing fixed height), it still looks like that: https://i.imgur.com/SKiauMr.png

Comment: @woaahmxtn Please show me the screenshot of all your constraints, maybe I'll try to do the same and see what happens.
Also show me the console error related to constraint (if any)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, your contraints are perfect.

Since you've not shared your code with us, I'll point out all the checkpoints.

First, check if you've used the `tableView cellForRowAt` function properly.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "thatCellsIdentifier", for: indexPath) as? YourTableViewCell else{
            fatalError()
        }

        cell.label.text = "sample"
        cell.image.image = UIImage(named: "yourImage")
        return cell
    }
```

**EDIT**
and now set this in `viewDidLoad()` of your TableViewController

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 300
```

or use the size inspector of your TableViewController to set it.

[image]
*(I've kept the estimate value as automatic in the screenshot, ignore it)*

Comment: Except for the optional handling, it looks identical: https://i.imgur.com/g2NYyMr.png

Comment: Interesting... I'll get back to this.